# It isn't a JSONObject. It isn't a JSONArray. What is it?

Tags: android, json

I have not been working with JSON very long.  I have the following response and I'm struggling to understand how to call the details of the "Topic".  I thought it was a JSONObject, but Android's logcat is telling me JSONObject["Topic"] not found.

```
[{"Id":1,"TopicId":1,"UserGuid":"C214ED74-07A7-409E-84FF-AF0457CF581A","Topic":{"Id":1,"AdminUserGuid":"C214ED74-07A7-409E-84FF-AF0457CF581A","Title":"Test Topic 1","AccessType":"public"}}]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure this is an array.

Comment: Also see the [JSON documentation](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses.  When I attempt to call it as a JSONArray get JSONObject["Topic"] is not a JSONArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a JSONArray with one element, a JSONObject with multiple properties, one of which is a JSONObject named topic:

```
JSONArray posts = new JSONArray(myJsonString);
JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject topic = post.getJSONObject("Topic");
```

Comment: That's what I thought too.  When I call getInt("Id") it works.  When I call getJSONObject("Topic") it tells me JSONObject["Topic"] not found.

Comment: @alockrem added what I would do to parse this object

Comment: I'm sure I had a character off somewhere.  When I paste your code in it works fine.  Other than string names I think my original code was almost identical and produced errors.  Thank you again.

Comment: I found it.  When I was attempting to extract the "AccessType" I incorrectly typed getString("Topic").  That was generating the error, not the object I spent the entire time troubleshooting.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to indent your JSON string this way you can understand the structure better 
It's a JSONArray with one object in which there are 4 objects and one of them has 4 attributes.

Comment: That is a great resource.  Thank you.  I am obtaining the value of "Id" by calling getInt("Id") instead of getJSONObject("Id").  What should I call to allow access to the "Topic"?